# Yarn 2 Monorepo VSCode cannot resolve Typescript types based on tsconfig.json settings

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, jestjs, yarnpkg, yarn-workspaces

I am working on a Yarn 2 monorepo using Yarn Workspaces, and in doing so I have run up against a wall in trying to get VSCode to resolve TypeScript types.

I have followed through with the information [provided by Yarn](https://yarnpkg.com/getting-started/editor-sdks) with respect to getting VSCode to resolve those types.

However, VSCode does *not* correctly resolve the types *unless*, in my `tsconfig.json`, I comment out the following two lines:

```
"include": ["src/**/*"],
"exclude": ["tests/**/*"],
```

This isn't a *huge* issue, since it works, but now when I build my typescript project I am including the `tests` folder in the build, which is not ideal.

Is there something I'm missing about the way these settings and Yarn are interacting? Is there a known workaround to get typescript to build correctly and for VSCode to resolve the types properly?

My full `tsconfig.json` is as follows:

```json
{
  // "include": ["src/**/*"],
  // "exclude": ["tests/**/*"],
  "compilerOptions": {
    /* Language and Environment */
    "target": "es2016",

    /* Modules */
    "module": "es6",
    "moduleResolution": "node",

    /* Emit */
    "declaration": true,
    "declarationMap": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "dist",

    /* Interop Constraints */
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,

    /* Type Checking */
    "strict": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the issue.

The TypeScript SDK used by Yarn uses `tsconfig.json` to figure out to which files it should be applied. If you use the `include` or `exclude` options in your `tsconfig.json`, the SDK used by Yarn will *also* apply those options. Thus, you need to have those options commented out within your base `tsconfig.json`.

The solution to have TypeScript include/exclude files as necessary is to have a specific configuration file you use for the build step.

Thus, you would have a `tsconfig.json` as follows:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2016",
    "module": "es6",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "declaration": true,
    "declarationMap": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true
  }
}
```

And you would have another file *not* named `tsconfig.json`, which contains the following:

```json
{
  "extends": "tsconfig.json",
  "exclude": ["./tests/**/*"]
}
```

That file can be named essentially whatever you would like; I chose `tsconfig.build.json` to be explicit about the fact that it is used only for the build step.

Then, in your package scripts, you need to call `tsc` with the `-p` flag, to which you provide the path to your `tsconfig.build.json` e.g. `tsc -p tsconfig.build.json`.

With this structure, you can have the best of both worlds; working IntelliSense *and* a clean `dist` folder.